# Retain data in topic that hasn't been processed yet

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I've set up tweepy to fetch tweets and write to a topic TWEEPY_TOPIC and a stream to read from the topic.

```
-- Create topic for tweepy to write into
CREATE STREAM TWEEPY_STREAM (
    id BIGINT,
    lang VARCHAR,
    tweet VARCHAR,
    user STRUCT<id BIGINT,
                screen_name VARCHAR>)
    WITH (
        KAFKA_TOPIC= 'TWEEPY_TOPIC',
        VALUE_FORMAT = 'AVRO'
        );
```

There's also another stream that reads from the above stream and writes it to another topic (which is pushed to elastic search using kafka-connect).

```
-- Create another topic with ML data.
-- GETSENTIMENT and GETFOURCLASS are custom ksql functions
CREATE STREAM ELASTIC_STREAM
WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'ELASTIC_TOPIC',
    VALUE_FORMAT = 'AVRO',
    PARTITIONS = 1, REPLICAS = 1
)
AS SELECT 
    id,
    lang,
    tweet,
    user,
    GETSENTIMENT(tweet) as sentiment,
    GETFOURCLASS(tweet) as fourclass
FROM TWEEPY_STREAM;
```

The user defined functions `GETSENTIMENT` and `GETFOURCLASS` make a POST request to a python model server which returns the classification. These API response currently take close to 0.5-1 second.

My concern is that if the data in the first topic `TWEEPY_TOPIC` is cleared after the default retention period (7 days), it will not get picked up by `ELASTIC_STREAM`. Is there any way to set some kind of a flag to tell kafka to not delete data that hasn't been processed yet? I'm open to redesign suggestions as well.

Comment: I would recommend to monitor the the lag of the application and if the lag grows, you could add new partition to the input topic and increase the parallelism of you query to ensure higher throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka does not have a clean up policy to only delete messages that have been consumed.

An alternative approach could be to use compacted topics. Compacted topics have a different clean up policy and the latest messages of all unique keys are kept.

Once a message has been consumed you could send a new message to the compacted topic with a null value. This marks that message as tombstoned and will be cleaned (deleted) by the Log Cleaner on the next compaction cycle.

Comment: Not sure if a compacted topic would work. It would require a unique key for each message of the input topic? I am not familiar with `tweepy` but if it produces message with `null` key, you cannot really do this. Or you first duplicate the data into a new topic an generate a unique key on-the-fly.